# an error has occurred in the script on this page line 0 char 0 code 0

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, com, mapquest

I am trying to incorporate a MapQuest map in an embedded browser object in a desktop application.

Amongst other problems I seem to bee getting a lot of this type of error:

> an error has occurred in the script on this page   Line 0
>
> Char 0
>
> Error script error
>
> Code 0
>
> URL http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.2.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key=mykey

What does this sort of error mean ?

Does it mean it has been unable to contact the URL to get the javascript file from the url at all hence line/char 0 ?

How can I prevent it ?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes (I had the same problem with the google Hosted librarys) its just the wrong line submitet from the `window.onerror` event.

You probably call a method from the external file, and in this method an error occurs.

Just download the javaScript file returned from `http://open.mapquestapi.com/sdk/js/v7.2.s/mqa.toolkit.js?key=mykey` and include it directly from your webspace (even better if you get the unminified version).

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply Nano. I'd really rather not download the library for several reasons. One I have to keep updating it and two I don;'t have a server to put it on as this is a desktop application. If there is some network communication problem with the MQ server then it probably wont be able to draw the map anyway ? Is there any way to trap/retry this situation ? Thanks

Comment: You just need to download the library once for debug propuse. If it is working, you can add the external library again. You can test it also at your localhost or wherever you use the library. So you dont need a webserver if its a javaScript only App

Comment: Thanks again. It does work some of the time now. ie I don't get the error and it does draw the map. So I think if it loads OK it is fine